# Eclipse Workspace on a network folder (UNC path)

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I am working on a project which has GitLab  repository and the local repository is on a network folder so I wanted to create an Eclipse Workspace on that folder as one can share the project with the other team members but when I tried to build the project I got an error message which says that eclipse workspace can't be a UNC path, so my question is, is there any work-around way I can do this, for example is there any way I can let the OS (Windows 10) link a local folder to the one on the network so that every member would do the same and work on his own local folder and it will be automatically edited in the network folder?
Thanks

Comment: It does not make sense having a Git repository on a network drive instead of cloning it. A Git repository on a network drive combines the disadvantages instead of the advantages: slow and potential editing conflicts. You can have an upstream repository on a network drive or you clone the GitLab repository to your local drive.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, what I mean by having the repository on the network folder is, it's cloned to a UNC path, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: When you clone a Git repository without the _bare_ option, there will be a working tree which is the location where the currently checked-out files are and this folder is not copied but mapped into your workspace. Everyone needs their own cloned, non bare Git repository to work with and then push their changes to the upstream repository.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that it doesn't make sense to work on a network with the Git rep.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible since **everyone needs their own** cloned **Git repository to work with**.

For instance, switching the branch or staging files are per repository and would therefore affect everyone. When you clone a Git repository without the bare option, there will be a so-called working tree which is the location where the currently checked-out files are and this folder is not copied but mapped into your workspace. Everyone would not have a copy of those files but working with the same files.

Besides the editing conflicts you would have, another disadvantage of having a Git repository on a network drive is that it would be slower. Therefore one would not want to have this even if it were possible to have Eclipse projects on a network drive.

But since in most cases a Git repository including the working tree takes less disk space than in SVN the working copy of the same, it should not be a problem if everyone has a locally cloned Git repository.